# LINQ joining two tables

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, join

I have two tables say A and B.
A cols are GUID, someintVar, someMoreIntvar
B col are GUID, someItemNO, SomeItemDesc

Now for one GUID I will have only one row in Table A. But I can have multiple rows for the same GUID.
Now I want to query the database based on GUID and select values in a class.
This class will have a list that will hold different rows coming from the second table. 
How can I do it?

Right Now I am getting many items in the result based on how many rows are there in the second table for that GUID.

```
var itemColl = from p in db.A
               join item in db.B on p.CardID equals item.CardID
               where p.CardID == "some GUID"
               select new 
               {
                   p.CardID,
                   p.secondCol,
                   p.ThirdCol,
                   item.ItemNo // How to add them in a collection or list.
               };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unested, but how about re-writing it a bit:

```
var itemColl = from p in db.A
               where p.CardID == "some GUID"
               select new {
                   p.CardID,
                   p.secondCol,
                   p.ThirdCol,
                   Items = db.B.Where(b=>b.CardID==p.CardID)
                      //.Select(b=>b.ItemNo) [see comments]
               }
```

Alternatively, you could perhaps group...

Comment: Thanks it is working. But just one thing. Its returning a list but not of type List<B>. How can I convert it?
Actually I am having a class with a List<B> property. I need to select this class object.

Comment: It is returning System.Collections.Generic.List I need it to have List<B>

Comment: just remove the .Select(b=>b.ItemNo) and the type will be List<B>

Comment: Sorry, I based that on the "item.ItemNo" in the final Select - just remove the Select

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a foreign-key relationship set up between A and B on GUID.  (And if you don't you db schema is broken and needs to be fixed)

```
var itemColl = from p in db.A
               where p.CardID == "some GUID"
               select new 
               {
                   p.CardID,
                   p.secondCol,
                   p.ThirdCol,
                   Items = p.Bs
               }
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming this is happening in the NEW or LOAD method of your class...this is how I would do it...

```
dim myAItem AS A = (from x in db.As WHERE x.CardID == MyGUIDValue).SelectSingleOrDefault

' Assign Variables Here
Me.AValue1 = myAItem.FromDbValue1

dim itemColl = (from b in db.Bs on b == MyGUIDValue).ToList 

me.ItemList = New List(of MySubClass)
For each bItem as B in itemColl
   dim item as New MySubClass
   'Assign Variables Here, ex: item.Value1 = bItem.MyDbValue1
   me.ItemList.Add(item)
Next
```