# linq for joining two tables

Tags: sql, linux, winforms

I have a lookup table below called AppraisalReadiness its joined on Readiness in the Appraisals list. How can i do this I am just a intermidate at linq its for use with telerik report how do i add a join in using the below query where is that possible ?

Thanks for any help in advance
AppraisalReadiness
    Code  description 
    1     Good work

```
   public List<appraisal> GetAppraisal(int employeeId)
    {
        List<appraisal> Appraisals = new List<appraisal>();

        try
        {

Appraisals = pamsEntities.appraisals.Where(a => a.emp_no ==   employeeId).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("GetAppraisal failed.", ex);
        }


        return Appraisals;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ joining two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611074/linq-joining-two-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq supports keywords that are very sql like.

```
from a in pamsEntities.appraisals
join b in pamsEntities.yourOtherTable on a.key equals b.foreignKey
where whateverYouWant
select new { a, b }
```

You will of course have to fill in the name of your other table as well as the names of the key/foreign key for the on clause, as well as change your select to whatever it is that you actually want to return, I can't give you more detail here unfortunately without knowing the schema of your tables.

Comment: thank you but how would I ensure it gets returned as a list ?

Comment: Just wrap the entire thing in ().ToList()

Comment: Appraisals= (from a in pamsEntities.appraisals
join b in pamsEntities.AppraisalReadinesses bas
where a.emp_no = employeeid 
select new { a, b }).ToList();


           ?? it still dont look right to me

Comment: Yes, that would work. Make sure you're either using var Appraisals (because the select is an anonymous object) for the declaration or else select specific objects that you already have somewhere instead of new { a, b }. In addition, where you have bas should be an on clause between a.something and b.something, just like a sql join would be.